# Bonjour does not work with TP-Link Archer C2

Tags: macos, bonjour

I recently bought a TP-Link Archer C2 router, and I am very satisfied with it so far. I have only a single problem: Bonjour service advertising seems to be broken.

**My network:**

- Simultaneous 2.4 and 5 GHz networks
- 2 Macs, 1 Ubuntu and 1 Windows 7 computer
- 3 iPhones, 2 Android phones
- HP printer
- Kindles, etc.

**What I tested:**

- The Macs do not see each other in Finder
- My Mac does not see the network printer (used to work)
- My Mac does not see the iPhone, when I start some app which provides WebDAV access and announces it with Bonjour
- Bonjour Browser shows only my local computers advertisements
- The iPhones do not see the AirPrint service of the printer
- I've tested using only a single WiFi band instead of both of them, did not help
- The router provides IP addresses from the same IP domain to all of the networks (192.168.0.1/255.255.255.0)

Where could the problem lie? What do I need to check to fix this? Is it maybe some multicast package forwarding issue? If so, where can I fix it?

Comment: This is a potential answer:
http://superuser.com/questions/730288/why-do-some-wifi-routers-block-multicast-packets-going-from-wired-to-wireless
:(

Comment: I don't think this is the issue for me. I had an older, 802.11n only TP-Link router, which worked perfectly with the same setup. The only reason I replaced it was the ac speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've contacted TP-Link's user support. In the result of this, they have improved the Bonjour support of the router in the 11/17/2014 software update:

http://www.tp-link.us/support/download/?model=Archer+C2&version=V1#tbl_j

So far (since 2 days) it seems working fine, so if you have similar problem, you only have to update your router.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any active devices between your Mac and the router? Bonjour packets have a TTL of 1.
Does running `dns-sd -B` on your Mac list your other devices? Does `dns-sd -F` show `local` as a browsing domain?
Try pinging: `ping 224.0.0.251` or `ping6 ff02::fb`

On the router, try enabling `Network > WAN > Advanced > Enable IGMP Proxy` and `IPv6 WAN > Advanced > Enable MLD Proxy` – it shouldn't affect multicast packets on the LAN, but you never know. :)
Try setting `Wireless 2.4GHz > Wireless Advanced > DTIM Interval` to `1`.
Try disabling anything firewall-related (`Security > Basic Security > Firewall > Enable SPI Firewall` and all the options under `Security > Advanced Security`), and if this solves the problem, re-enable them one by one.

Comment: It seemed to solve the issue for a while, but after some days the same happened. Sometimes bonjour sharings are working, sometime not. :(

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with the TP-Link Archer C50. Bonjour devices would just not show up. 
I had originally set up the router as an access point, basically extending an existing LAN with additional WiFi.

What solved the problem for me was configuring the router *as a router*, that is, selecting this option:

[image]

Before enabling it, you will have to plug in something into the WAN port. Then, after enabling it, unplug the cable, wait for the router to restart. Now connect your PC again, navigate to `192.168.0.1` (the router's default address), and change the *Network » LAN* address of the router to something other than your existing router's IP. Restart, then go to *DHCP* and disable the built-in server. Restart once more and the router should work.